# Strange in React Native not showing err

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a strange situation with a React Native app.
The part of the code with problems is this:

```
const request = async (options) => {
  const defaults = {baseURL: 'base URL'}
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  console.log('this is logged')
  if(token) {
      console.log("this is logged")
      const headers = {
    'TokenAuth': token
  }
      Object.assign(defaults, headers: headers);
  }
  console.log('this is NOT logged anymore')
  options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
};
```

The idea is that i can't see anywhere the javascript error.

The error is on Object.assign(defaults, headers);
Why i can't see it ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean you cant see error? what is the error?

Comment: The app is stopping at console.log('this is NOT logged anymore') and i can't see any error in Chrome console or in node.js console.

Comment: I created a codepen where is the problem? [Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/WillWillman/pen/NWWgxGM?editors=1111)

Comment: what do you expect to do with options? i don't see you using it anywhere or returning it so the function just appears to be finishing and returning nothing (and doing nothing)

Comment: The error is on Object.assign(defaults, headers: headers); In pure javascript it's showing an error but in React Native not.

Comment: can you post the whole component?

Comment: I've added the whole component.

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole component:

```
import constants from './../constants/constants';
import axios from 'axios';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import * as Utils from '../configs/utils'

const request = async (options) => {
  const defaults = {baseURL: constants.BASE_URL}
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  if(token) {
      const headers = {'TokenAuth': token}
      Object.assign(defaults, {headers: headers});
  }
  options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

  return axios(options)
        .then(response => {
          return response.data 
         } )
        .catch( error => {
          if (error.response.status == 401) {
            Utils.deleteToken();
          }
          let errResponse = 'Bad Error'
          throw errResponse;
        });
};
export function getAllTodos() {
  return request({method: 'get', 
                baseURL: constants.BASE_URL,
                url: '/api/items',
                })
}
```